# Getting MalformedURLException: Protocol not found?

Tags: android

I am getting **MalformedURLException: Protocol not found**, when I am trying to load image from URL sting. That image is displaying in Browser when I paste that URL. But not displaying in ImageView. I've used this code:

```
 public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {

    try 
    {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);

        return myBitmap;
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    }
```

Please anybody tell me whats the problem? It will be very helpful to me.

Comment: can you show us your image url?

Comment: Thanks everybody for your support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its a

```
http://74.208.68.90/webservice/images/image44.png
```

Your code is OK.

Comment: Hey yeah. You are right. Its the mistake from webservice. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

malformedexception comes when there is some problem in your url

try to encode your parameters in url with url encoder and protocall not found shows
http is missing from your url

```
String url = url +"/" + UrlEncoder.encode(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is "src" that may have problem,